# How do you prevent scrolling? (HTML5 Game in Mobile Device)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, scroll

How do you prevent scrolling in mobile devices?

I already tried these 3 solutions (But still don't work) :

1. In CSS

   ```
   body {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: fixed;   (tried absolute too)
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     margin:0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
   ```
3. ALSO: I can't use:

   ```
   document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){e.preventDefault();});
   ```

because of other requirements.

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your code ?